# Netbeans unexpected return value error

Tags: java, netbeans, javafx

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/trl2Y.png)

The error used to be in another line, which was just a blank line, in the same file but i opened the file with Notepad++ and removed the whitespaces and let Netbeans reload and it moved to the package declaration.

Am i going crazy and im not seeing the obvious error or is it an issue with Netbeans ?

Im using Version 8.0.2

Comment: Post your code not a link to a partial image

Comment: The error stays even if i delete everything except the package declaration.

Answer (score -1):

Clearing Netbeans Cache fixed the Issue.

It's located at

```
C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache
```